# Watir-webdriver : Can't set text box until page refresh

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

This is the situation:

- Only happens with chrome.
- Only on linux.
- Only with text_field element.

I've got a text box. First time I set it, it works.

`browser.text_field(:id =>'name').when_present.set myname`

Now, when i try doing the same command again, the browser simply does not respond at all( no error given).
Only when i refresh the page with `browser.refresh`,

only then the command works ( and again only the first time ,until next refresh)

I've done:

- Checked if the textbox is `present?`, and it is.
- tried to set sleep for 1 min after each `set`.

Any ideas on why this could be happening?

Comment: @Mike, have you tried to use  text_field instead of text box? Do you have an "input type=text"?

Comment: Its of course a text_field, My mistake :) Changed it in the question.
And yes, i have the `input type`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
browser.text_field(:id =>'name').when_present.value = myname